# Going to Italy for 2 days then back to UK for 4 days then to France for 2 weeks. Which embassy should I apply to for my Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, france, uk, schengen, italy

I've got a dilemma. I am going on my holiday to France for two weeks in July but few days before that I need to fly to Italy for 2 days. So my traveling plan is: going to Italy for two days then back to the UK then a week later going to France for two weeks. What embassy should I apply for my Schengen visa? French or Italian. I'm scared that if I apply for the Italian one (where I'm going for two days) and then a week later will go to France for two weeks I might have problems. Or if I apply for the French embassy but then my first country I will enter on this visa will be Italy I will have trouble. I know traveling within the Schengen countries should be no problem but I need to go back to UK in-between so I won't have the continuation of the trip. Don't know what to do!!!

Comment: The general Schengen rules relevant to the previous question apply but OTOH practical experience with either the French or Italian embassies and/or border control could also be useful and specific to this question.

Comment: Nominated to reopen: Clearly not a duplicate at all, the other question is from someone who already has a visa, this one is about where to apply.

Answer (score 3):

As your first trip is to Italy, you need to apply there and then as Rudy suggested ask for a multiple journey visa, covering the entire period.

You can then safely return from Italy and then use the same visa to go to France for your holiday.