# Can I get a multi-entry Schengen visa if travelling to two different countries on two separate trips?

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry

I am travelling to France for 2 days in October and then I would be back in the UK. Later in November I would be travelling to Spain for 4 days. Is it possible for me to apply for a Schengen visa at the French embassy, despite that:

- There is a 25 day gap between my two trips
- The duration of stay in France is less than the duration of stay in Spain

Would the French embassy consider granting me a multi-entry visa for such an itinerary?

Comment: French embassy will likely only issue you a visa for France.  But can you make a question into a question?

Comment: Do you mean France will issue visa only for 2 days even if I provide my itinerary of my Spain trip?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.  The max stay may not be 2 days but it is unlikely to give you a multi entry visa given that your second trip is to Spain.

Comment: @Karlson that comment should be an answer.

Comment: @chx I can't make it an answer since I have nothing to bavk it up.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66554/32134

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, that's not how it's supposed to work and there are many reasons why each consulate might want to avoid giving a visa for the other trip you are planning, see [Visiting two Schengen countries, coming back home in between, do I apply for single-entry or multiple-entry visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46689/visiting-two-schengen-countries-coming-back-home-in-between-do-i-apply-for-sin) and [Applying for a Schengen visa when there is a gap between trips to main destination and country of entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66554/applying-for-a-schengen-visa-when-there-is-a-gap-between-trips-to-main-destinati) for more details.

That said, as a UK resident, you might get lucky. I have heard about some folks who got a one-year multiple-entry visa the first time around without even asking for it or planning another trip. It does make sense: Someone who resides in the UK has made it through the rather arduous process of getting a UK visa, can have many opportunities to go mainland Europe but little incentive to stay there and earn money illegally. All this makes you a low-risk applicant and the consulate could save everybody some effort/money by giving you a multiple entry visa.

Finally note that there is a third type of visa that would seem to fit your itinerary, namely the two-entry visa. In many respects it's closer to a single-entry visa than to a multiple-entry visa. It was intended to make it possible for foreign tourists (but not necessarily residents) to add a stay in British isles in the middle of a tour of Europe without having to worry about requesting two visas on the road.

Comment: The almost always give a multiple entry visa. However, the it could be limited to just to travel dates provided by the OP.