# Applying for two Schengen visas at the same time

Tags: visas, schengen

I'm a resident of Uzbekistan. 
I have to be in Norway from June 24 to August 5, (tourist visa) (42 days). Then I will have to leave for the US, for 15 days. 
From August 25 till October 25, (60 days), I have to be in Austria (student visa).

Can I apply for two visas at the same time? 
If not, will there be any problem to apply for the second visa in the US, being a non-resident?

Comment: There are some discrepancies in your days count:
August 5-25 is 20 days not 15 days and August 25-October 25 is 62 days not 60 days.

Comment: You can find more info (but unfortunately no real solution for your problem) in http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46689/visiting-two-schengen-countries-coming-back-home-in-between-do-i-apply-for-sin and all linked questions.

Comment: You write you are a _resident_ of Uzbekistan, but which country are you a _citizen_ of?

Comment: Oh, sorry for confusion. I am the citizen of Uzb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. It would also be very difficult to go to Norway and apply for the Austrian visa during your stay in the US (it would be difficult - time wise - if you were a resident and not being a resident makes things even more difficult). As others have already commented, the length of your trips is also a problem, slightly over the limit for short stays, and would need to be adjusted to be doable with short-stay visas.

Austria being your main destination and apparently an important one (as you would be studying for 60 days!), I think the most reasonable course of action is to get in touch with the Austrian consulate and apply there first. Depending on what they tell you, you have two options:

- Applying for a Schengen visa. It could even cover both trips if you make sure to stay less than 90 days in total and get a multiple or two-entry visa. But I am not sure they would be willing to issue such a visa (as opposed to a single entry visa covering only the Austrian part of the trip), especially if that's the first time you are applying for a Schengen visa.
- Applying for an Austrian national visa. This would solve the length of stay issue and leave you free to apply for a Schengen visa from Norway afterwards. But I don't know whether a suitable visa is available from Austria, how much it costs, what would be required to get it and whether they would issue it for a stay that's under the short-stay threshold (when considering only the stay in Austria…)

In either case, when you apply, you should attach a letter explaining your plans carefully and why you want them to issue a somewhat unusual visa. But be prepared to get only a regular Schengen visa for Austria and to have to forgo your trip to Norway. I am just bringing bad news but also realise that a refusal is a very real possibility, you need to make sure your application is very strong to get even that.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to adjust your travels plans as there is rule that in any 180 day period you can be in Schengen area for maximum of 90 days (source: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/21461/12462 ) Your stay in Norway and Austria are 102 days in total.  They are separated by 15 days stay in US but they still in same 180 period so you need to shorten you stay in Schengen area from 102 days to 90 days.

I entered your travel plans into this official caculator http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/schengen_calculator_en.html and result is "Days of stay in the 180-days period from 29/04/16 to 25/10/16: 104 day(s)
Overstay in the period from 12/10/16 to 25/10/16 (14 days)"

Comment: Huh. Does a student visa count into the 90/180 rule? I seriously doubt! Why is this upvoted so heavily...?

Comment: Does your comment mean I still have a chance?

Answer (score 1):

If you have both visas "Visitor" like "Visitor general" and "Visitor - study" then you need to change your plan a bit.

If you second visa is "student" not a "visitor". 
You should be able to apply for both visas now in advance.
90 days rules should not apply to you, as your second visa is "student".

You can not apply for visa in US, if you will stay there just for 15 days.

Comment: Are sure about second part of your answer?
This answer  http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/21461/12462 says about the 90/180 rule: "In any case, the rule always applies to a person. It does not matter if you have several passports, visas or nationalities."

Comment: @Rfilip, it counts for all visitor visa but Student visa are different and allow longer stays.

Comment: That's broadly correct but I don't think that this is the official terminology and could be somewhat confusing. What the OP needs from Austria is not a Schengen visa at all but a national or “type D” visa. I don't know how realistic this is in this situation but she needs to find out what's available in Austria and probably use another form/set of documents to apply for it.

Comment: @Rfilip Sorry that my answer to the other question was confusing, I meant several Schengen (i.e. short stay/type C) visas.

Comment: Could you please clarify why i cannot apply for visa while i am in the US?

Comment: @Lina Many countries require you to be a _resident_ (e.g. long-term student, work visa, permanent resident) of the country where you are physically present when you apply for a visa.